# Putting manually created buttons into an array

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 100 buttons in a panel. They are named btn1-btn100. I am trying to put them into a list. This is what i have so far:

```
    public void buttonList()
    {
         List<Button> panelButtonList = new List<Button>();
         for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
       {
         panelButtonList.Add(btn + x);
       }

    }
```

the name btn doesn't exist in current context? I'm new would be greatful for any assistance

Comment: you need to initialize a button, and you wouldn't add it to x.

Comment: This looks like another case of _optimistic coding_. Are you thinking that `btn + x` will take the string "btn", convert the value of `x` to a string, concatenate the two strings and then, in a stroke of inspiration, realize that the resulting string just _happens_ to match the name of an object and that maybe using the object itself would be a cool idea?

Comment: You cannot do that so easily. C# is a strongly-typed language. This means that you can't do `btn + x` to concatenate a variable name. The only way to do that, is to go through reflection, and it can easily get messy.

The best way at this point is for your buttons to be generated in your code rather that use the name of the variable, especially because a solution that is based on strings is not very adaptable to changes and can break VERY easily. In my opinion, you should refactor your code rather than looking for a solution the concatenating the name of the control.

Comment: I recommend some simple iteration over the controls collection of the panel. It doesn't even have to involve the ids if there are no other buttons in the panel. If there are just white list based on the id.

Comment: Because you dont create an instance of button named `btn` so you get :

> name btn doesn't exist in current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Button> panelButtonList = this.YourPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

Try the above. You might have to add a where clause if there are other buttons that you don't want included. If needed you can white list based on the id range.

Comment: no I want all buttons in the panel just none outside, that works a treat thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a FindControl method. Build your control name "btn"+Convert.ToString(x)